# How Run A Stored Procedure (with Parameters - Has A return Value) From Code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How can I use a stored procedure (with parameters - has a return value of type `int`) from code behind?

My stored procedure looks like this :

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay]
    @Co_ID int
AS
-----------------
Declare @Sum bigint
-----------------
BEGIN
    SELECT
       @Sum = SUM(TotalPay)
    FROM Noskheh
    WHERE
       (Co_ID = @Co_ID)

    RETURN @Sum
END
```

I want to use `@Sum` in code behind ...

Would you please show me a way for doing that ?

Thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: This is very dependent on what DB library you're using (Enterprise Library, ADO.NET, etc).

Comment: You should change your last statement to: `SELECT ISNULL(@Sum, 0)` or something like that; if your `@Sum` ends up being NULL, return 0 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand`. If you have your code with the `RETURN @Sum` statement in the end, you need to do this (define a parameter of type RETURN_VALUE):

```
using(SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay", _conn))
{  
   _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CO_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
   _cmd.Parameters["@CO_ID"].Value = 5; // whatever value you want

   _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.BigInt));
   _cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 

   _conn.Open();
   _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   Int64 result = Int64.Parse(_cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value);

   _conn.Close();
}
```

It would be a lot easier if you would replace that RETURN statement with a simple SELECT:

```
SELECT @Sum
```

In that case, you can use the simplified version I had before - using `.ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve the single value of the single row being returned from the stored proc:

```
using(SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay", _conn))
{  
   _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CO_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
   _cmd.Parameters["@CO_ID"].Value = 5; // whatever value you want

   _conn.Open();
   object result = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   _conn.Close();

   Int64 sum = Int64.Parse(result);
}
```

That should call your stored proc, read the single value you're returning, and converting it into an `int` variable called `sum`.

Comment: Also, for the love of all that's holy, don't do this in your code behind. Split it into a separate class.

Comment: @David Lively: totally agree with you!

Answer (score 2):

There is [no shortage](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/storedprocedure12052007003126AM/storedprocedure.aspx) of [tutorials](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574) on [this subject](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+.net+stored+procedure).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an SqlParameter `@Sum` with Direction set to `ReturnValue`

Example:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand():

cmd.Connection = // place your SqlConnection object;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "StoreProcedureName";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sum", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: thanks for your answers // but i have a very bad error that i do not know how can i handle it // error is like : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The 'sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead. in the line of ____object result = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();_____

Comment: You **should** put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects (and anything IDisposable, really) into `using(...) { .... }` blocks to make sure they get properly freed when going out of scope - just a good Best Practice to follow....

Comment: thansk for ur updates // but i hate this error : The conversion of the nvarchar value '3955811801' overflowed an int column.
The 'sp_Noskheh_SumOfTotalPay' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead. // I changed @Sum Type To nvarchar // i do non know where is the int column!!!!!!!!!  // this error will appeear in line _______cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
_______      ////// is something wrong in ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @LostLord, what type is TotalPay column?

Comment: @LostLord you must check type of column TotalPay, if it is int then is the problem. You must change type of that column or Cast value of that column.