# Stored Procedure Not working from c# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure within C#.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.CommandText = "updateData";
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inrego", rego));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inOprt", oprt));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inService", service));

      connection.Open();

      int update = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      Console.WriteLine(update);

      connection.Close();
    }
```

update shows 1 on console, but the database still isn't updated.

This is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].updateData
@inrego varchar(5),
@inOprt char(3),
@inService as varchar(50)

AS
delete from buses where rego = @inrego;
insert into buses (rego, operator,service) values(@inrego, @inOprt, @inService);
RETURN 0
```

Running the stored procedure manually works, aka

```
USE [C:\USERS\---\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2013\PROJECTS\---\TEST.DB.MDF]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[updateData]
        @inrego = N'1',
        @inOprt = N'2',
        @inService = N'3'

SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

GO
```

works, and successfully updates the database, but the code form C# doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492536/how-run-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters-has-a-return-value-from-code-behi?

Comment: I suspect you might just need "dbo.updateData" for the call.

Comment: Just tried it @EugenePodskal. Same results unfortunately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Modified it to add dbo at the start, but still not working

Comment: @matthew5025 Hmm, are you really sure that nothing changes in the database? Also, try only to delete, or only to insert in procedure, or try to modify few tables at once.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Yeah, the database isn't changing at all. Also, a select command works, but update/delete/insert isn't.

Comment: @matthew5025 . . . Perhaps it is a permissions issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Turns out using a db file won't work, but using a SQL server works... Hmmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been unable to reproduce the issue on clean local database(MS SQL EXPRESS 2013, Win 8.1, .NET 4.5):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].buses
(
    [rego] varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [operator] char(3),
    [service] varchar(50)
)
```

```
static void UpdateOrInsertBuses(String rego, String oprt, String service)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "updateData";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inrego", rego));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inOprt", oprt));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inService", service));

            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                int update = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(update);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...
// Add data
UpdateOrInsertBuses("11", "12", "13");
UpdateOrInsertBuses("21", "22", "23");

// Update added
UpdateOrInsertBuses("21", "22", "Changed for sure");
```

So, it is some issue that does not relate to your current code. As it has been suggested by @ Gordon Linoff it is either a permission issue, or some trigger that meddles into the updates, or the database for some reasons reverts or ignores any changes.

Comment: I'm actually "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" as the data source, I'll try using a SQL server.

Comment: So, it is the issue pertinent only to database files, not for hosted one? Hmm, I'll try later with database file DB, just to check.